# How to handle projects at the same level with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have two (Java) projects, a library and an executable which uses the library. The two projects reside in subfolders of the same folder but I don't want to add anything (like settings.gradle) in the root folder (they come from different git repositories, thus, I cannot have the files in the common parent source controlled). Here is my layout:

```
lib - has some runtime dependencies (from the maven repo)
app - depends on lib and has some (different) runtime dependencies
```

The goal is to produce a folder (Gradle's build\libs is good enough), containing a jar file and a lib subfolder with all runtime dependencies. What is the best approach with Gradle? Here is the result I am looking for:

```
app\
   build\
      libs\
         app.jar
         lib\ - all dependencies are here
```

With ant for instance, I bring everything together when building the executable (referencing the lib's source code via ../lib/). That's somewhat ugly, but get's the job done. Ideally, I would think that it's more flexible to have the lib build as a dependency, when building the executable, just adding another jar to the app's lib subfolder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can put your root `build.gradle` file and the `settings.gradle` file in a folder named `master` next to your lib and app folder:

```
lib - has some runtime dependencies (from the maven repo)
app - depends on lib and has some (different) runtime dependencies
master - root build.gradle file + settings.gradle file
```

gradle looks for a master folder when searching for a settings.gradle file